# Get width or height svg rectangle javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I can get the width of my object svg in javascript and save the value in a variable. this is my object

```
    <rect id="cercle1" x="5" y="25" width="50" height="50"  stroke-width="1" stroke="#0E0E0E" style="fill:red; stroke:black; stroke-width:2"; />
```

I try this:

document.getElementById('cercle1').width.value;

thanks for help

Comment: BTW, you can have `style="…"` or presentation attributes, but you do not need both with conflicting values. e.g. either `stroke-width="1"` **or** `style="stroke-width:2px"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the getAttribute function:

```
document.getElementById('cercle1').getAttribute("width");
```

That will get you the String from the HTML code. As [Phrogz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405017/phrogz) mentioned it, you might want a number instead, or the actual value (that might be different). If so, refer to [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410653/get-width-or-height-svg-rectangle-javascript/26410836#26410836).

Comment: Note that this returns a string value. While JavaScript is loosely-typed and silently attempts to do the right thing when converting a string to a number, it's not always correct. You probably want to use `+...` or `*1` to convert to a real number.

Comment: @Phrogz That is true, it all depends on how you need to use it. In some cases this will be sufficient, in others, your method will be a better deal.

Comment: For me, this didn't work, but I used JS getBoundingClientRect(). Maybe because I hadn't assigned a value to "width"

Answer (score 6):

The [`width`](http://objjob.phrogz.net/svg/object/131) attribute is an [`SVGAnimatedLength`](http://objjob.phrogz.net/svg/object/15) property. As such, you need to:

```
// If you want the original value
var w = document.getElementById('cercle1').width.baseVal.value;

// If it is animated and you want the current animated value
var w = document.getElementById('cercle1').width.animVal.value;
```

Or, if just want what's in the source code:

```
var w = document.getElementById('cercle1').getAttribute('width')*1; // convert to num
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("cercle1"); // reference to the object tag
var rect = obj.getBoundingClientRect(); // get the bounding rectangle
alert(rect.width);
alert(rect.height);
```

Or this:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("cercle1"); // reference to the object tag
var svgdoc = obj.contentDocument; // reference to the SVG document
var svgelem = svgdoc.documentElement; // reference to the SVG element
alert(svgelem.getAttribute("width"));
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jf7yn33u/) example.

From the comments from Phrongz: Note that the bounding rect will account for transforms, which may or may not be desired.

Comment: +1 was relevant for me in the case that the svg has modified its w & h dimensions and those height & width attributes were no longer correct.

Comment: This is the actual solution which would work even if viewbox is set and the svg element is resizing through the parent

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you had created your rect dynamically, then the below solution is valid

```
var rect = document.createElementNS(svgns, "rect");
rect.setAttribute('width', '200px');
rect.setAttribute('height', '200px');
var width= rect.width.baseVal.value;
var height= rect.width.baseVal.value;
```